# Declaração de ArrayList com o tipo ou sem

Tags: java, declaração-de-variável

Gostaria de saber a diferença em declarar um `ArrayList` desta forma:

```
List<BancoPerguntas> listaBancoPerguntas = new ArrayList<BancoPerguntas>();

List<BancoPerguntas> listaBancoPerguntas = new ArrayList<>();
```

No segundo exemplo não passo a entidade no `ArrayList`.

Existe alguma diferença?

Comment: Isto se chama [***Inferencia de tipo***](http://blog.globalcode.com.br/2011/11/type-inference-no-java-7-generics-com.html). apenas declarando o tipo do lado esquerdo, o java automaticamente considera o operador diamante vazio(<>)do lado direito com o mesmo tipo, deixando a declaraçao mais curta e sucinta.

Comment: Inferência de tipo foi introduzida no Java 7. A diferença além da declaração ficar mais curta é que a partir dessa versão se você não usar inferência o compilador passa a acusar um aviso (warning), que não chega a impedir a compilação.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 7):

Já foi dito que é a inferência e acho que dá para inferir (*pun intended*) nos comentários que é apenas uma diferença sintática sem afetar semântica, performance ou qualquer outra questão.

O que está fazendo no segundo exemplo é apenas omitir algo que o compilador já sabe, só não está escrito, mas a informação ainda está lá.

Em Java 10 é possível fazer diferente em variáveis locais:

```
var listaBancoPerguntas = new ArrayList<BancoPerguntas>();
```

Novamente o `var` muda nada, o compilador lê o que está do lado direito da expressão e vê que faz uma atribuição e através dela o tipo pode ser determinado mesmo sem estar explicitamente escrito no local que deveria. Pensa bem, pra que digitar duas vezes a mesma coisa?

Também é possível fazer:

```
var x = 1;
```

e

```
var y = retornaUmInt();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Generic.java).

Mas não costuma-se recomendar esse último caso porque fica menos legível saber que tipo é a variável.

Há casos que não é possível usar a inferência, até porque o tipo da variável precisa ser diferente do tipo do construtor/literal.

É muito complicado fazer o mesmo para variáveis de instância, então não é permitido.

Java está melhorando :)

Answer (score 6):

Os dois códigos são equivalentes. A segunda forma com o diamante (`<>`) foi introduzida no Java 7 com o objetivo de deixar a sintaxe dos tipos genéricos mais enxuta, evitando a redundância de ter que declarar o tipo genérico tanto na invocação do construtor quanto na declaração do tipo.

Quando o compilador encontra o diamante, ele olha para a declaração da variável para descobrir o que deveria ser colocado lá. Dessa forma, o compilador transforma a segunda forma na primeira.

Há também uma terceira forma introduzida no Java 10:

```
var listaBancoPerguntas = new ArrayList<BancoPerguntas>();
```