# Erro no Netbeans usando Java: "error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5"

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou tentando usar um `List` de `List`s em Java no NetBeans pela primeira vez:

```
List<List<String>> listao = new ArrayList<>();
```

Mas ele apresenta um erro de compilação na linha onde eu tenho a lista:

> error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5

E apresenta a dica:

> use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator

Ok, mas que source é esse, e como fazer isso?

Comment: A dica é clara, voce precisa usar uma versao do jdk 7 ou superior pra usar operador diamante. Sua versao é 1.5 nao suporta.

Comment: Relacionada: [Declaração de ArrayList com o tipo ou sem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/287805/28595)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, clique com o botão direito do mouse no seu projeto pra ver o menu suspenso da figura abaixo, onde você vê o item "Propriedades" ou "Properties":

[image: Menu suspenso]

Ao abrir as propriedades, altere a caixinha do formato do código-fonte para JDK 7 ou maior:

[image: Java 7]